# Executing a gem behind proxy

Tags: ruby, proxy, rubygems

Recently I installed [gettc](https://github.com/seri/gettc), a gem that allows offline practise for topcoder problems. Executing the gem gives me the following error:

```
C:\Users\shivshnkr>gettc 11127
You have given ID = 11127
getaddrinfo: No such host is known.
```

I managed to install this gem by using the following:

```
set HTTP_PROXY = username:password@yourproxy:port
```

But it doesn't work for running the script. Please help.

Comment: `getaddrinfo: No such host is known.` it says that there is not internet connection from that(or this?) side...

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ it worked when i tried using it at my home during the weekends, where there is no proxy